# Does $n^2+1\nmid n!$ hold for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory

How many positive integers $ n $ satisfy that $ n^2+1 \nmid n! $; are there infinitely many?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365712/prove-that-there-exist-infinitely-many-integers-n20151-mid-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OEIS entry [A144255](http://oeis.org/A144255) states that H. Iwaniec, *Almost primes represented by quadratic polynomials*, Invent. math. $47$, $1978$, p. $171$–$188$, proves that there are infinitely many primes or semiprimes of the form $n^2+1$. If $n^2+1$ is a prime, then it doesn't divide $n!$. If it's a semiprime, one of its two prime factors is $\ge\lceil\sqrt{n^2+1}\rceil=n+1$, so again it doesn't divide $n!$. Thus there are indeed infinitely many $n$ such that $n^2+1\nmid n!$.

Whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$ appears to be [an open problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44126).

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I hear the Semiprimes  : )