# Is there a way to notate {there exists infinitely many integers $n$} in symbols?

Tags: notation

If I wanted to write, *there exists an integer $n$* then in symbols this would be written as $$\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$ If I wanted to write, *there exists only one integer $n$* then in symbols would be written as $$\exists!n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$ Sometimes this could be mistaken as *there exists $!n$* but if so that would be written as $$\exists(!n)\ \lor \ \exists\{!n\}.$$ But what if I wanted to write *there exists infinitely many integers $n$*. I can’t write $$\exists \text{ infinite } n \in\mathbb{Z}$$ or perhaps $$\exists\text{ inf }n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ can I? If not, is there some mathematical notation to denote this? I thought of something like $$\operatorname*{\text{Exi}}\limits_{n\to\infty}\tag{inspired by $\lim_{n\to\infty}n$}n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ but before I make something up, I want to know for sure if there does not exist a notation of this sort yet. This question came to me after looking at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365712/prove-that-there-exist-infinitely-many-integers-n20151-mid-n).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Dap thank you very much. You should put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like :
$$ \exists A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}), \ |A|=\infty, \quad \forall n \in A, \ \cdots  $$
(or card$(A)=\infty$)?

Comment: If you can so easily write $|A| = \infty$, why bother with $A$ at all? Just $|\Bbb Z| = \infty$ would work fine, no? And this entire question would be moot.

Comment: @Arthur : you are totally right about $\subset$, it was a (corrected) misprint, thank you! For the second part, we want to say that "there exists infinitely many integer", here the set $A$, not all of them ; but I'll add a part to make it more clear.

Comment: What is $\text{card}(A)$? I assume that is read as *the cardinal of $A$*, right?

Comment: @user477343: yes it is and a quite used notation.

Comment: @Netchaiev I use $n(A)$ or $\#A$ to denote that (particularly the latter when I have already used $n$ as a variable) but I have never seen $\text{card}(A)$ before. Thanks for that :)…… And by the way, I would prefer something like $\text{crd}(A)$ or something (just giving my opinion; of the notation).

Comment: @user477343: Ok :) I've seen already $\# A$.

Comment: Also, from the duplicate answer, do you know how we would denote *there exists at least one integer $x$* or something along those lines? Perhaps, $$\bigg(\operatorname*{\exists}^{\geqslant 1}x \ \lor \ \operatorname*{\exists}_{\geqslant 1}^\infty x\bigg)\in\mathbb{Z}$$ or something like that?