# Positive integers $n$ with $n^5 - 5n^3 + 5n + 1 | n!$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Find all positive integers $n$ such that $n^5 - 5n^3 + 5n + 1 | n!$

I know that $ n^5-5n^3+5n+1=(n+1)(n^4-n^3-4n^2+4n+1)$, but I have no idea where to go from here.

This was from a local contest.

If there are an infinite amount, I would like to know like a "general" solution.

Comment: Well, a natural first step is to simply search.  Maybe you can learn something by examining small $n$.

Comment: There's an old post here, with something similar like $n^9+1 \mid n!$, and it got answered. I can't find the link.

Comment: $693, 4613, 5587, 5873, 6000, 6239, 7293, 7660, 7964, ...$.  Sequence doesn't seem to be in OEIS (yet).

Comment: @BartMichels May be you were thinking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1370243/11619)? Joni Teräväinen's answer in particular. I'm afraid Schinzel's theorem is above my paygrade.

Comment: Yes! Great you found it!

Comment: The zeros of that quartic are $2\cos(2^k\pi/15)$ with $k=1,2,3,4$. In other words, it splits in the real subfield of the fifteenth cyclotomic field. I betcha that plays a role.

Comment: For its part, that comes from the connection to Chebyshev polynomials. If $P(x)=x^5-5x^3+5x$, then $$P(2\cos\alpha)=2\cos5\alpha$$ for all $\alpha$.

Comment: I suspect the contest screwed this up. The quintic polynomial $f(n)$ given should be better than $n$-smooth infinitely often and, with a little work, one should be able to show that for many of these values, we have $f(n) \mid n!$. An explicit characterization of such $n$ would be surprising to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, the explicit despiprion of such $n$ is beyond our possibilities. But for infiniteness of such $n$ user Math1Zzang on mathlinks proved the next generalization of your problem (post #3 here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1793837p11880596):

For every positive integer $m$, there exists polynomial $P_{m}(x)$ such that $P_{m}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=x^{m}+\frac{1}{x^m}$.
Then there exists infinitely many positive integers $n$ for which $P_{m}(n)+1|n!$