# Resources about infinite primes of form $n^2 + 1$

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

Where can one find existing work on the following problem?

> Prove there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2 + 1$.

Resources about related work would also be appreciated.

Comment: the problem is open. You want resources that contain partial progress?

Comment: There is a more general conjecture on the infinitude of prime outputs of certain polynomials : http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture

Comment: Look at this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44126/primes-of-the-form-n21-hard The best partial progress for the polynomial values that are prime (in two dimensions though) is the work of Iwaniec and Friedlander http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander–Iwaniec_theorem

Comment: These primes are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A002496 and you might want to start by looking at some of the references and links on that page.

Answer (score 2):

This is an open problem, considered very difficult with the current state of number theory. Landau [posed this problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems) more than 100 years ago, and it still has no solution.

As others have pointed out in the comment section, this is a more general *sub-problem* of the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: I doubt Landau *originally* posed this problem. Euler worked on this, see http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/originals/E283.pdf

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut True, edited.