# infinitude of primes with the form $n^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any progress in proving the infinitude of prime numbers of the form $n^2+1$ ?

Comment: This is not the right place for this question...I suppose....

Comment: If it was, it would need to be narrowed down: Any progress since when, for example? What do you define as progress? Otherwise, it is a fairly wide-open question.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14690/primes-of-the-form-a21

Comment: @vrugtehagel
i get that  $p=n^2+1$$\Rightarrow2\sum_{i=0}^{i=n-1}i^3\equiv n\pmod p$
but it doesn't help me with anything. :D

Comment: The problem is very hard (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44126/primes-of-the-form-n21-hard)), and there were no new headlines, I think.