# Are there infinitely many primes such that...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there infinitely many primes $p$, such that,

$p-1=n^2$
where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

As $p$ must be $odd$, we can say that $p$ must be of the form $4k+1$. But I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: you may see this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44126/primes-of-the-form-n21-hard