# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

When $n>3$, $n$ must be $\equiv 0, 2 \pmod 6$

$3$, $7$, $43$, $73$, $157$, $211$, and $421$ are primes,
but $343=7^3$ ($n=18$) is not.

Are there infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+n+1$ ?

Comment: What makes you think that the answer to this question is known?

Comment: If you'd like to know, an affirmative answer to this problem would lead to a breakthrough

Comment: by accident, I was observing uniqueness of positional numeral systems which all digits are same (likewise 111,444,666...)

Comment: Is this an open problem?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a single example of a non-linear polynomial which is known to take on infinitely many prime values.  Of course, there are lots of conjectures regarding this issue, notably [The Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: Yes, it is a special case of the Bunyakovsky conjecture, see [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44126/primes-of-the-form-n21-hard).

Comment: incredibly difficult... it's scaring me

Comment: @JayC.Lee The problem is open, but very likely the answer is that there are infinite many such primes.

Comment: similar to your polynomial are these two polynomials which also produce primes $p(n)= n^2 + n - 1$ and $p(n)= n^2 - n + 1$ I noticed that the first one produces more primes but it may change if we test larger and larger number $n$.